# SELECT department_id, department_name, location_id, city FROM departments d Natural JOIN locations i using(location_id);

Tags: oracle10g

**why is the query returning**: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and on removing the Natural keyword, it turns true(it executes)?????????

Answer (score 2):

You either let Oracle do the join for you (using `natural`) or you do it explicitly.

Taken [from Oracles documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html)

The following two statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES NATURAL JOIN CITIES

SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES JOIN CITIES
USING (COUNTRY, COUNTRY_ISO_CODE)
```

You need to choose one approach or the other - at the moment you're trying to mix the two.